# check if html item present on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked before, but those solutions arent working for me. It may have to due with images used.

**here is my html:**

```
<div id="tour">
    <section class="first js-background"> // this section is repeated 5 more times
        <div class="background js-first"></div>//image located in here 300 px height
        <div class="copy">
            <h6>Line one</h6>
            <h1 class="space large">Line two</h1>
            <h6>Line three</h6>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**javascript to check if visible:**

```
 $('.js-background').each(function(x, item) {
      var $current = $(item),
      $window = $(window),
      elemTop = $current.offset().top,
      elemBottom = elemTop + $current.height(),
      docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),

      if ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
    && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) ) {
         //do code here if true
      }
 }
```

I also tried this [plugin](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/)

**with code:**

```
if ($current.visible()) {
   //if visible do something
}
```

With both types of code, when I trigger the function with only the first section visible in browser window. The if statement returns true 6 times.

The images are backround not img tag

css:

```
#tour .first .background{
    background: url('/Content/images/1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: please add more details

Comment: Is the image a background of `. background` or is there actually an `<img>` inside of it? If there's an `<img>` is it always there, or is it only there if the image is visible?

Comment: How are the sections hidden? Javascript? CSS? Is the the sections that are hidden or the contents thereof? Can you provide a jsFidle?

Comment: they arent hidden. thats why i avoiding using the term visibility initially. due to section size (i.e height) their are only two sections located on the page at any time. i only want to take action of those sections that are located on the page. not the ones off page (outside browser window)

Comment: Don't use dots in classes: `class="first js-background"`

Answer (score 0):

i have not understood your problem , but to check if an element is present in the page use `length`.
For example to check if `div` with `id='tour'` exists page:

```
 if($('#tour').length>=1) { 
    //some code here
  }
```

Comment: by present on page I mean visible in browser window

Comment: I need to know which of the six sections are currently located/visible in the browser window

Comment: better use `$("#tour").length !== 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `:visible` check.  Just select the element like `if($('.first').is(':visible')){ 
//do something 
}`

Comment: That's doesn't take into account whether the user has scrolled down far enough to see the element, which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Tidied your code a little, no `.` in the `class=""` and separate `var` for every variable, seems to work for me on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/DC8qn/) (if you scroll down in the 5 seconds it gives you the correct alerts)

```
$('.js-background').each(function(x, item) {
  var $current = $(item);
  var $window = $(window);
  var elemTop = $current.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $current.height();
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  if ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
&& (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop) ) {
     alert(x + ' is visible');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for separate var statements. For anyone wondering why, read this: http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/